# Python multiprocessing creates sub-process using wrong function

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I'm trying to write code that create sub-process using another module(demo_2.py),
and exit program if i get wanted value on sub-processes.

But result looks like this.

[image: Unexpected action on my code. This is a screenshot of the result]

It seems that demo_1 makes two sub-process that run demo_1 and load demo_2.
I want to make sub-process only runs demo_2.

What did i missed?

demo_1.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from multiprocessing import Process,Queue
import sys
import demo_2 as A

def multi_process():
    print ("Function multi_process called!")
    process_status_A = Queue()
    process_status_B = Queue()
    A_Process = Process(target = A.process_A, args = (process_status_A,))
    B_Process = Process(target = A.process_A, args = (process_status_B,))
    A_Process.start()
    B_Process.start()
    while True:
        process_status_output_A = process_status_A.get()
        process_status_output_B = process_status_B.get()
        if process_status_output_A == 'exit' and process_status_output_B == 'exit':
            print ("Success!")
            break
    process_status_A.close()
    process_status_B.close()
    A_Process.join()
    B_Process.join()
    sys.exit()


print ("demo_1 started")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    multi_process()
```

demo_2.py

```
class process_A(object):
    def __init__(self, process_status):
        print ("demo_2 called!")
        process_status.put('exit')
    def call_exit(self):
        pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if process_status_A == 'exit' and process_status_B == 'exit':
```

should be

```
if process_status_A_output == 'exit' and process_status_B_output == 'exit':
```

---

Conclusion: The naming of variables is important. 
Avoid long variable names which are *almost* the same (such as `process_status_A` and `process_status_A_output`).
Placing the distinguishing part of the variable name *first* helps clarify the meaning of the variable.

So instead of

```
process_status_A_output
process_status_B_output
```

perhaps use

```
output_A
output_B
```

---

Because Windows lacks `os.fork`,
on Windows every time a new subprocess is spawned, a new Python interpreter is started and **the calling module is imported**.
Therefore, code that you do not wish to be run in the spawned subprocess must be ["protected" inside the if-statement](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows) (see in particular the section entitled "Safe importing of main module"):

Thus use

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print ("demo_1 started")
    multi_process()
```

to avoid printing the extra `"demo_1 started"` messages.

Comment: That explains why my code never ends and acts as i wanted only on Linux.(Not tested on macOS)  Thank you!